# Azure Function - Portal Code Deployment feature is skipping build

Tags: azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I have create a function app using visual studio code and then published it. Function app works fine. I am now using code deployment feature(KUDU) in the function portal and its skipping the build. Below is the log

```
9:55:46 AM       Updating submodules.   
9:55:47 AM       Preparing deployment for commit id '5642d3aeec'.   
9:55:48 AM       Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip 
9:55:48 AM       Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip    
9:55:48 AM      Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled). 
9:55:49 AM      Syncing 4 function triggers with payload size 452 bytes successful. 
9:55:50 AM      Deployment successful.
```

Deployment is happening when ever the code is checked in to Github. But its not picking the latest code. I did set the app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to "1".

What changes do I need to make to pick the latest build.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar scenario and a similar experience, but I did not manually set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, though I found it set to 1.  I assume it was set by the VS Code deployment, which first created the Azure Functions App.  Then when I switched to using Kudu Continuous Integration, the setting was still around.  I deleted that setting from **Configuration**, and now the problem is fixed.

Comment: For anyone working out why their python dependencies aren't getting installed on function host from CICD this fixed my issue thanks!